# autoscrolling memo in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Does delphi contain a component that allows auto scroll text loaded from db, like in news sites?

Tt's for a delphi 7 application and requires a vertical scrolling.

Comment: The answer from @vcldeveloper is best, but another option to consider is simply to add lines to the `TMemo` (or similar) VCL control in reverse order. This puts the latest item on top which may remove the need to scroll at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of those solutions for scrolling worked for me in the RichEdit memo. Using Delphi 2010 + w7.
But this one works perfectly:

After every `Lines.Add('...')` this follows:

```
SendMessage(RichEditMemo.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
```

Found in:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_10120212.html

Answer (score 46):

For such a simple task, you don't need to buy a commercial component! All you need to do is to send an EM_LINESCROLL message to that memo control, to make it scroll to the last line:

```
procedure ScrollToLastLine(Memo: TMemo);
begin
  SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0,Memo.Lines.Count);
end;
```

If your memo is read-only to users and is updated automatically by the application, you can put a call to the above procedure in its OnChange event-handler, so that whenever the text inside the memo is changed, it is automatically scrolled down to the last line.

Comment: Hmm, That shorter than mine, Memo_Scroll Golf anyone?  :)

Comment: this scroll is way to fast. how do slow it down?

Comment: @none, what do you mean by slowing it down? Are you going to make a visual effect of scrolling?

Comment: yea, some kind. like news flash scrolling memo.

Comment: So don't want a scrolling memo at all... You need to paint the text onto a TPaintbox and then slowly scroll the painting position :)

Answer (score 5):

Possibly, to save you some money you could adapt this to scroll a DBMemo:

```
EchoMemo.Lines.Add('A Line of text or more');
EchoMemo.SelStart := EchoMemo.GetTextLen;
EchoMemo.SelLength := 0;
EchoMemo.ScrollBy(0, EchoMemo.Lines.Count);
EchoMemo.Refresh;
```

I use for a log display.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Memo.GoToTextEnd;` when needed, for example inside an onchange event. Is not a proper auto-scrolling effect but can be useful in similar situations.

Comment: Note - this apparently for FMX, not older VCL apps

Answer (score 3):

The right thing to send messages within the same application is to use the [Perform](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform) command, SendMessage sends it to the windows stream while perform sends it directly to the component. So much so that he doesn't even ask for the handle:

`memo1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);`

Comment: `SB_LINEDOWN` scrolls one line down, so you have to know how many times to call it to scroll enough. The answer with `EM_LINESCROLL` scrolls to the end with just one call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with DevExpress components, you should use `InnerControl->Handle`. So it should look like this:

```
SendMessage(cxMemo->InnerControl->Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0,cxMemo->Lines->Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally regarding the need to scroll a TControl (can be a TMemo) to a specific position, here is what says the official RAD Studio /Delphi documentation as an example of usage of [TControl.Perform](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/TControlPerform_(Delphi))

=> use the `Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0)` method